# Using input-group inside an inline form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

When appending an `input-group` to a `form-inline`, the `input-group` appears below the form on a "new line" instead of inline with the other controls.

It seems that this is because the `input-group` wrapper class has `display` set to `table` whereas the other inputs, which work fine, have their `display` set to `inline-block`. Of course, it is not possible to give the `input-group` the `inline-block` display because its child `add-on` span, which has `display: table-cell`, needs the property of the parent to align correctly.

**So my question is:** is it possible to use `input-group` inside an inline form *using Bootstrap classes exclusively*? If not, what would be the best work-around *allowing the use of custom classes*.

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/26ZM4/2/) illustrating my point. The code is the following:

```
<form action="" class="form-inline">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Works with" style="width: 100px;"/>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Text Inputs" style="width: 120px;"/>

    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" /> and Checkboxes
        </label>
    </div>
    <select class="form-control" style="width: 150px;">
        <option>and Selects</option>
    </select>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">and Buttons</button>
    <div class="input-group" style="width: 220px;">
        <span class="input-group-addon">BUT</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="not with input-groups" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This is a bug, maybe in your case you can use `pull-right` in the `input-group` class.

Comment: Yes this may be a bug. And using `pull-right` is not a good solution regardless of my case: the vertical spacing between inputs is lost and if there are two input-groups they are displayed wrongly. IMHO it is better to use a functioning solution with custom classes rather than an erroneous hack with built-in classes.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This was indeed a bug and was resolved (check the [issue on github](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9382) for more info).

From now on the inline forms in BootStrap require to wrap the child form controls with `.form-group`.

So my code would become:

```
<form action="" class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Works with" style="width: 100px;"/>
    </div>

    ...
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group" style="width: 220px;">
            <span class="input-group-addon">BUT</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="not with input-groups" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm on 3.0.3 and I still have this problem. Adding the input-group-addon after the form-control creates a new line

Comment: @Marc : I'm on 3.0.3 and to do what you want I do "form.form-inline {    display: inline; } form.form-inline .form-group .input-group input + .input-group-addon { width: initial; }". I don't know if it's compatible with all the browsers.

Comment: @Marc : I forgot to say the input need a width or max-width.

Comment: +1 I wish this was more apparent in the documentation!

Comment: Working example of @edsioufi 's answer using Bootstrap 3.2.0:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kevinfunk/d62nfe90/)

Comment: This didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need to separate your form into columns to get the inline layout you want. An example (I think of what you're after) is on the Bootstrap site [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons-segmented).

try putting

```
<div class="col-lg-1"></div>
```

around your controls to see what I mean. You of course need to work in columns of 12 so this will need to be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: We can use columns for aligning any form controls (regardless of the problematic `input-group`). Still, BootStrap provides the `form-inline` class (which would be unnecessary if it was encouraged to use columns). This [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/26ZM4/4/) makes me think that the reason behind the existence of the inline form is that using columns does not yield good results from a responsive design point of view. I would still prefer custom classes to the columnar design (or even fall back to `horizontal-forms` instead).