# Inline Form nested within Horizontal Form in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to build a form in Bootstrap 3 like this:

[image]

My site (not the above link) just updates from Bootstrap 2.3.2 and the format is not correct anymore.

I cannot find any doc about this type of form on [getbootstrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com).

Could anyone tell me how to do this? Only 'Username' would be OK.

Thanks.

**PS** There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201835/form-inline-inside-a-form-horizontal-in-twitter-bootstrap) but it's using Bootstrap 2.3.2.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

I have created a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/r7hgjjzv/) for you.

Here is how your nested structure should be in Bootstrap 3:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="birthday" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Birthday</label>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
        <div class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="year"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="month"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="day"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice how the whole `form-inline` is nested within the `col-xs-10` div containing the control of the horizontal form. In other terms, the whole `form-inline` is the "control" of the birthday label in the main horizontal form.

**Note** that you will encounter a left and right margin problem by nesting the inline form within the horizontal form. To fix this, add this to your css:

```
.form-inline .form-group{
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know why (maybe something broken in last bootstrap.css) but in your [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a3vAP/4/) fields `year`, `month` and `day` placed not inline but each on another row.

Comment: Oh it is because small width of screen on jsfiddle. Adding  class `col-xs-3` to `<div class="form-group">` solved the problem.

Comment: Why do you use `<div class="form-group">` within the `form-inline` anyway?  I'm not using it, and the margins work themselves out without any custom CSS.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @IsaacBetesh this is a requirement of Bootstrap to avoid problems that can occur when using an `input-group` within the `form-inline` (for more info see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18194737/2274357) to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18189398/2274357))

Comment: This structure doesn't seem to provide any control over nested field widths?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the adjustment to left/right margin for form-inline. That was the last missing piece to get my radio buttons aligned vertically.

Answer (score 16):

Another option is to put all of the fields that you want on a single line within a single `form-group`.

[**See demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/a3vAP/296/)

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-10" name="name" placeholder="name"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="birthday" class="col-xs-3 col-sm-2 control-label">Birthday</label>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="year"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="month"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="day"/>
        </div>    
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Helped me some how. +1

Comment: This option works well as long as you put fields into a form group which actually belong to the it. Think of additional `has_error` classes which must be applied at the same node as `form-group`. When you mix different fields and labels within a form group this bootstrap semantic would break.

Answer (score 8):

This [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/127826) example seems like a much better option. Only thing is that the labels are a little too high so I added `padding-top:5px` to center them with my inputs.

```
<div class="container">
<h2>Bootstrap Mixed Form <p class="lead">with horizontal and inline fields</p></h2>
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-1" for="inputEmail1">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5"><input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail1" placeholder="Email"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-1" for="inputPassword1">Password</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5"><input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword1" placeholder="Password"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-12" for="TextArea">Textarea</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6"><textarea class="form-control" id="TextArea"></textarea></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-3"><label>First name</label><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"><label>Last name</label><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-12">Phone number</label>
        <div class="col-sm-1"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="000"><div class="help">area</div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-1"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="000"><div class="help">local</div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="1111"><div class="help">number</div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="123"><div class="help">ext</div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-1">Options</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Option 1"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Option 2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<hr>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

To make it work in Chrome (and bootply) i had to change code in this way:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-10" name="name" placeholder="name" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="birthday" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Birthday</label>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <div class="form-inline">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="year" />
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="month" />
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="day" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This contains broken/invalid HTML.

Comment: @JimmyObonyoAbor I am a bit late to the party... But you were too, back in 2016... When reformed said the html is invalid it actually was invalid... it got fixed not even a month before your comment

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler solution, without all the inside `form-group` elements

```
<div class="form-group">
       <label for="birthday" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Birthday</label>
       <div class="col-xs-10">
           <div class="form-inline">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="year" style="width:70px;"/>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="month" style="width:80px;"/>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="day" style="width:100px;"/>                        
           </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

... and it will look like this,

[image]

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I had problems aligning the label to the input(s) elements so I transferred the label element inside the form-inline and form-group too...and it works..

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-10">
        <div class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="birthday" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Birthday:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="year"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="month"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="day"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```