# How do I adjust Bootstrap 3 inline form width?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a form that relies on Bootstrap 3:

[image: Imgur]

**full working example**: http://jsfiddle.net/x7vk7/2/

The gist is that I have 2 columns for content. The first column is `col-lg-4`, and the second is `col-lg-8`. The first column displays a form, and the 2nd column displays results.

The problem I'm having is related to the width of the inline form elements in the Cases question. I used [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429121/inline-form-nested-within-horizontal-form-in-bootstrap-3) to figure out how to properly nest inline form elements in a horizontal form. Here's the relevant code I have for the Cases question:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="id_current_case_count" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="How many cases have you seen?">Cases</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <div class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="id_current_case_count" min="0" name="current_case_count" type="number" />
            </div>
            ±
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="id_case_count_uncertainty" min="0" name="case_count_uncertainty" type="number" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control" id="id_case_count_interval" name="case_count_interval">
                    <option value="weekly">per week</option>
                    <option value="total">total</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that I want all 3 form elements for the Cases question to be on the same line. The first 2 elements are just integer fields, so it's not necessary for them to be very wide. What's the proper way to adjust the width of those first two integer fields so that all 3 fields fit on the same line?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to achieve [this](http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/Q64XH/embedded/result/) all you have to do is to use this code insted of yours:

```
<div class="content row">
    <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding-right: 5px;">
        <input class="form-control" id="id_current_case_count" min="0" name="current_case_count" type="number" />
    </div>                            
    <div class="col-xs-3"  style="padding-right: 5px;">
        <input class="form-control" id="id_case_count_uncertainty" min="0" name="case_count_uncertainty" type="number" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <select class="form-control" id="id_case_count_interval" name="case_count_interval">
            <option value="weekly">per week</option>
            <option value="total">total</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

All the code in [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/Q64XH/).

Comment: Sorry for the slow response (been at a conference), but that looks great! I'm gonna try it out tomorrow. I think this'll solve my issues. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

The recommended way stated in the documentation is to wrap the input in a parent element, and set the column width there.

```
<div class="col-xs-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=".col-xs-2">
</div>
```

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-sizes

In your example you already have them wrapped in a div so just add the col-class to your form-group.

Comment: This is close to working, but there's an issue with the spacing between elements (see http://jsfiddle.net/x7vk7/4/ for an example). You can see that the elements are actually sitting on top of each other. This covers up the ±, too. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: It depends on the size of your browser how it is rendered. Note that bootstrap3 is very adaptive, i.e. if you have a narrow display, it will split it up to several lines for it to fit properly. One thing that I noticed in your jsfiddle, is that the width of three controls (and the +/-) don't add up to 12 properly. I suggest that you put <span class="col-xs-2"> around the +/-

Comment: Ok, here's a link to the current jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x7vk7/7/. It still looks off (see http://i.imgur.com/1ASVV5S.png). I'm widening the browser to make maximal use of col-lg-*, and the form elements are still sitting on top of each other. I just don't know how to prevent that from happening.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Bootstrap's column classes within any element group. In this case, your problem can be solved by giving each of your `.form-group` divs in the section in question an additional class of `.col-xs-4`. This will size each of them to be 1/3 of the available space, and all on the same line.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x7vk7/3/)

Comment: I definitely like where you're going, but the example you provided doesn't quite work. http://i.imgur.com/EgZeGWo.png is what it looks like. Also, the ± is missing (I do need that there).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set the `.col-lg-4` to width="40%" or whatever else you want it set to. I use this myself so i don't see why it shouldn't work.

Example,

```
.col-lg-4 {
width: 50%;
}
```

Make sure this is in a separate CSS file that is is added in the HTML AFTER the bootstrap is.

Example,

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/local.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Uh, you should really not override bootstrap's classes but add your own class with your custom css

Answer (score -1):

Add style="width:33%;display:inline-block;" to your input tags or a class containing the same.

Comment: I tried adding `style="width:30%;"` to the form-group (see http://jsfiddle.net/x7vk7/5/), but it's not working. The inputs just sit on top of each other. How can I make them sit next to each other instead of on top?

Comment: @Geoff you also need to add display:inline-block

Comment: Crap, I'm still seeing the same thing: http://jsfiddle.net/x7vk7/6/. The inputs are still on top of each other.

Comment: @Geoff you can't simply go on merging the answers. Remove your col classes

Comment: I don't follow. This fiddle has nothing to do with the other 2 answers. There are no col classes on these form-groups, unless I'm misunderstanding.