# MVC with Bootstrap: mixing alignment of controls

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a form-horizontal  with controls that have "form-control" class applied. This is made by Mvc scaffolder.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())     
{ 
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  <div class="form-horizontal">
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Data, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Data, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Data, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Sometimes i want to align two fields inline, but i can't find the way. 
I see Bootstrap made all inline or all horizontal forms, but not a mix of them.
My goal is not to touch (if possible) the structure of scaffolded razor view.

|______|

|______| |______|

|______|

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18429555/473016)

Comment: Thanks!! But the code has little bug, so i apply a change to make it work in Chrome and Bootply.